# How to use an environment variable in a environment variable in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to have a environment variable COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME with the value denpal-4 for a Jenkins job with build_id 4.

```
environment {
  COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = 'denpal-$(BUILD_ID)'
}
```

The alternative would be writing this in every sh-block

```
sh ''' 
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = 'denpal-$(BUILD_ID)'
code...
'''
```

This would go against the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) principle however. Is something in environment {} possible?

UPDATE/ANSWER: double quotes instead of single quotes fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can assign the value to variable in environment stage (using **env** as a prefix to the variable) and then can use it in any stage, please see below:-

```
environment {
           env.COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = "denpal-${BUILD_ID}"
        }
```

Comment: WorkflowScript: 12: Expected string literal @ line 12, column 5.
       env.COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = 'denpal-${BUILD_ID}'

Comment: Double quotes fixed it!